# How to calculate K-Dops faster?

Tags: c++, collision-detection, bounding-boxes

I have my general understanding of K-Dops for collision detection.

I understand how to calculate them. I also understand the super slow way of recalculating them.

Example: I have a simple model of a character. Pre-process calculate k-dop bounds. Let's say his right leg. The second he bends his leg, let's say for a jump. I have to recalculate his k-dops to make sure the collision system is checking properly.

Now the way I think of doing it is: Animate the vertices and, now that they are in their new proper location, recalculate the K-dops.

I feel like that's super slow. Because if that leg is made up of many triangles, that process is just drastically slowed down. At that point I might as well just use a simplified geometry model instead of k-dops for collision testing.

Does anyone have know ways to speed up the K-Dop recalculation process? Especially if it were to happen dynamically and occasionally. Not just pre-processed.

Comment: You can use fattened k-dops and only update them sometimes. In general k-dops aren't good for things that rotate and re-orient all the time.